# How to deal with different badges in Postgres Explain Visualizer?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.2, performance-tuning, postgresql-performance

I've been working with several DBMS during my career, but always Oracle/Sql Server/MySql. Now I have to deal with PostgreSQL and my first task is to tune several queries to speed them, as our DB is growing much faster than expected.

The query is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM some_view_name
WHERE (1 = 1) 
    AND field1 = 'whatever' 
    AND field2 >= 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_TEXT' ORDER BY field3, field2 ASC;
```

Related view is a complex join of tables and more views. And it runs quite fast when field2, that's a text date field, is something near to current date. But as date is increased (in the past) it slows, and slows, and... for a query about `current_date - 1 year` it can take almost 20 minutes to complete, returning 2,234,407 rows. Complete view has 17,475,533 rows.

I'm working on analyzing the mean of the inner view code because I'm new at this environment and still don't know functionality. While I discover how to reformulate the view/query I've come over [Tatiyants' Postgres EXPLAIN Visualizer (pev)](https://tatiyants.com/pev/#/plans) and I've read a ton of posts in blogs, StackOverflow and here about Postgres performance. But I'm still not sure how to begin tunning my queries. The first thing that's annoying me is the badge `bad estimate`. **What should I do with this?** I have several nodes with this badge, like Bitmap Index/Heap Scan (both), Nested Loop, Sort, Merge... In one of the nodes, execution plan said "underestimate rows by 124x". I've run `ANALYZE` in the DB, rerun execution plan and when reloading it in PEV now it says "underestimate rows by 132x". So what should I check/evaluate in order to make this badge disappear?

As PEV plans are stored locally, I'm posting a screenshot of it:
[image: PEV Explanation]

```
select version();

> PostgreSQL 9.2.24 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC)
> 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28), 64-bit
```

Related to DB config, I guess config parameters have been left by default after installation, but can check them if there is any parameter relevant to this situation. I don't have access to production server so I can't post hw config, but can ask if needed.

I'm aware of materialized views and the performance improvement they provide, and I know there are solutions to implement them in PostgreSQL versions prior to 9.3 (where they were introduced), but by now this is not a solution to take in consideration. Also upgrade Postgres version is not a solution by now.

Any suggestion will be really appreciated.

**EDIT:** 
Explain plan in text:

```
Sort  (cost=378583.87..378620.19 rows=14528 width=178) (actual time=213051.194..214405.039 rows=3015686 loops=1)
  Output: pos_boyas.id_traza_boya, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.usuario_controller, imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei, imeis_isn_tbl.isn, imeis_isn_tbl.imei, pos_boyas.num_boya, pos_boyas.latitud_boya, pos_boyas.longitud_boya, pos_boyas.estado_tracking, pos_boyas.estado_flash, pos_boyas.estado_sos, pos_boyas.estado_ack, pos_boyas.estado_gps, pos_boyas.bateria, pos_boyas.fecha_posicion, pos_boyas.velocidad, pos_boyas.rumbo, barcos.id_barco, barcos.nombre_barco, (COALESCE((CASE WHEN (public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0)), (COALESCE(estados_notify.zona_prohibida, 0)), (COALESCE(estados_notify.velocidad_lenta, 0)), (COALESCE(estados_notify.sin_transmision, 0)), imeis_isn_tbl.alias
  Sort Key: imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei, pos_boyas.fecha_posicion
  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 588440kB
  Buffers: shared hit=9793574 read=5194007 dirtied=11 written=983, temp read=408320 written=408306
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=78087.84..376288.01 rows=14528 width=178) (actual time=38788.260..177034.008 rows=3015686 loops=1)
        Output: pos_boyas.id_traza_boya, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.usuario_controller, imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei, imeis_isn_tbl.isn, imeis_isn_tbl.imei, pos_boyas.num_boya, pos_boyas.latitud_boya, pos_boyas.longitud_boya, pos_boyas.estado_tracking, pos_boyas.estado_flash, pos_boyas.estado_sos, pos_boyas.estado_ack, pos_boyas.estado_gps, pos_boyas.bateria, pos_boyas.fecha_posicion, pos_boyas.velocidad, pos_boyas.rumbo, barcos.id_barco, barcos.nombre_barco, COALESCE((CASE WHEN (public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0), COALESCE(estados_notify.zona_prohibida, 0), COALESCE(estados_notify.velocidad_lenta, 0), COALESCE(estados_notify.sin_transmision, 0), imeis_isn_tbl.alias
        Buffers: shared hit=9793574 read=5194007 dirtied=11 written=983, temp read=73952 written=73938
        ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=78087.84..251384.24 rows=14528 width=166) (actual time=38788.197..130480.296 rows=3015686 loops=1)
              Output: public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.usuario_controller, imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei, imeis_isn_tbl.isn, imeis_isn_tbl.imei, imeis_isn_tbl.alias, pos_boyas.id_traza_boya, pos_boyas.num_boya, pos_boyas.latitud_boya, pos_boyas.longitud_boya, pos_boyas.estado_tracking, pos_boyas.estado_flash, pos_boyas.estado_sos, pos_boyas.estado_ack, pos_boyas.estado_gps, pos_boyas.bateria, pos_boyas.fecha_posicion, pos_boyas.velocidad, pos_boyas.rumbo, barcos.id_barco, barcos.nombre_barco, (CASE WHEN (public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
              Hash Cond: ((barcos.id_barco = barcos.id_barco) AND (usuarios.id_usuario_controller = public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller))
              Buffers: shared hit=221373 read=2784664 dirtied=5 written=186, temp read=73952 written=73938
              ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=957.57..91273.92 rows=2771388 width=12) (actual time=17.736..4808.980 rows=2771388 loops=1)
                    Output: barcos.id_barco, usuarios.id_usuario_controller, CASE WHEN (public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                    Hash Cond: ((barcos.id_barco = barcos_tbl.id_barco) AND ((usuarios.usuario_controller)::text = (public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.usuario_controller)::text))
                    Buffers: shared hit=74 read=168
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..34768.76 rows=2771388 width=25) (actual time=0.039..1567.517 rows=2771388 loops=1)
                          Output: barcos.id_barco, usuarios.usuario_controller, usuarios.id_usuario_controller
                          Buffers: shared hit=60 read=32
                          ->  Index Scan using usuarios_controllers_tbl_pkey on public.usuarios_controllers_tbl usuarios  (cost=0.00..75.26 rows=1149 width=21) (actual time=0.025..6.553 rows=1149 loops=1)
                                Output: usuarios.id_usuario_controller, usuarios.usuario_controller, usuarios.id_usuario_controller_zcc, usuarios.cuenta_demo, usuarios.ver_boyas, usuarios.ver_todos_barcos
                                Buffers: shared hit=56 read=15
                          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..57.18 rows=2412 width=4) (actual time=0.000..0.581 rows=2412 loops=1149)
                                Output: barcos.id_barco
                                Buffers: shared hit=4 read=17
                                ->  Seq Scan on public.barcos_tbl barcos  (cost=0.00..45.12 rows=2412 width=4) (actual time=0.009..1.234 rows=2412 loops=1)
                                      Output: barcos.id_barco
                                      Buffers: shared hit=4 read=17
                    ->  Hash  (cost=777.81..777.81 rows=11984 width=25) (actual time=17.670..17.670 rows=11984 loops=1)
                          Output: barcos_tbl.id_barco, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.usuario_controller
                          Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 722kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=14 read=136
                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=248.43..777.81 rows=11984 width=25) (actual time=3.373..14.056 rows=11984 loops=1)
                                Output: barcos_tbl.id_barco, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.usuario_controller
                                Hash Cond: (usuarios_controllers_barcos_tbl.id_barco = barcos_tbl.id_barco)
                                Buffers: shared hit=14 read=136
                                ->  Hash Join  (cost=173.16..522.78 rows=11984 width=25) (actual time=2.428..8.821 rows=11984 loops=1)
                                      Output: public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.usuario_controller, usuarios_controllers_barcos_tbl.id_barco
                                      Hash Cond: (usuarios_controllers_barcos_tbl.id_usuario_controller = public.usuarios_claves_usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=5 read=124
                                      ->  Seq Scan on public.usuarios_controllers_barcos_tbl  (cost=0.00..184.84 rows=11984 width=8) (actual time=0.009..2.028 rows=11984 loops=1)
                                            Output: usuarios_controllers_barcos_tbl.id_usuario_controller_barco, usuarios_controllers_barcos_tbl.id_usuario_controller, usuarios_controllers_barcos_tbl.id_barco
                                            Buffers: shared read=65
                                      ->  Hash  (cost=158.79..158.79 rows=1149 width=25) (actual time=2.410..2.410 rows=1149 loops=1)
                                            Output: public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.usuario_controller, public.usuarios_claves_usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller
                                            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 67kB
                                            Buffers: shared hit=5 read=59
                                            ->  Hash Join  (cost=68.71..158.79 rows=1149 width=25) (actual time=0.953..2.172 rows=1149 loops=1)
                                                  Output: public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.usuario_controller, public.usuarios_claves_usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller
                                                  Hash Cond: (public.usuarios_claves_usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller = public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=5 read=59
                                                  ->  Hash Join  (cost=32.85..107.14 rows=1149 width=4) (actual time=0.448..1.317 rows=1149 loops=1)
                                                        Output: public.usuarios_claves_usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller
                                                        Hash Cond: (public.usuarios_claves_tbl.id_usuario = public.usuarios_claves_usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario)
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=4 read=50
                                                        ->  Seq Scan on public.usuarios_claves_tbl  (cost=0.00..58.49 rows=1149 width=4) (actual time=0.008..0.412 rows=1149 loops=1)
                                                              Output: public.usuarios_claves_tbl.id_usuario, public.usuarios_claves_tbl.usuario, public.usuarios_claves_tbl.clave, public.usuarios_claves_tbl.salt, public.usuarios_claves_tbl.clave_original, public.usuarios_claves_tbl.clave_anulada, public.usuarios_claves_tbl.estado
                                                              Buffers: shared hit=2 read=45
                                                        ->  Hash  (cost=18.49..18.49 rows=1149 width=8) (actual time=0.431..0.431 rows=1149 loops=1)
                                                              Output: public.usuarios_claves_usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario, public.usuarios_claves_usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller
                                                              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 45kB
                                                              Buffers: shared hit=2 read=5
                                                              ->  Seq Scan on public.usuarios_claves_usuarios_controllers_tbl  (cost=0.00..18.49 rows=1149 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.226 rows=1149 loops=1)
                                                                    Output: public.usuarios_claves_usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario, public.usuarios_claves_usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller
                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=5
                                                  ->  Hash  (cost=21.49..21.49 rows=1149 width=21) (actual time=0.499..0.499 rows=1149 loops=1)
                                                        Output: public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.usuario_controller
                                                        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 61kB
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=1 read=9
                                                        ->  Seq Scan on public.usuarios_controllers_tbl  (cost=0.00..21.49 rows=1149 width=21) (actual time=0.004..0.252 rows=1149 loops=1)
                                                              Output: public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.usuario_controller
                                                              Buffers: shared hit=1 read=9
                                ->  Hash  (cost=45.12..45.12 rows=2412 width=4) (actual time=0.939..0.939 rows=2412 loops=1)
                                      Output: barcos_tbl.id_barco
                                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 85kB
                                      Buffers: shared hit=9 read=12
                                      ->  Seq Scan on public.barcos_tbl  (cost=0.00..45.12 rows=2412 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.520 rows=2412 loops=1)
                                            Output: barcos_tbl.id_barco
                                            Buffers: shared hit=9 read=12
              ->  Hash  (cost=76571.36..76571.36 rows=14528 width=166) (actual time=38768.035..38768.035 rows=3015686 loops=1)
                    Output: public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.usuario_controller, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller, imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei, imeis_isn_tbl.isn, imeis_isn_tbl.imei, imeis_isn_tbl.alias, pos_boyas.id_traza_boya, pos_boyas.num_boya, pos_boyas.latitud_boya, pos_boyas.longitud_boya, pos_boyas.estado_tracking, pos_boyas.estado_flash, pos_boyas.estado_sos, pos_boyas.estado_ack, pos_boyas.estado_gps, pos_boyas.bateria, pos_boyas.fecha_posicion, pos_boyas.velocidad, pos_boyas.rumbo, barcos.id_barco, barcos.nombre_barco
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 8 (originally 4)  Memory Usage: 152904kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=221299 read=2784496 dirtied=5 written=186, temp written=64451
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=364.41..76571.36 rows=14528 width=166) (actual time=513.666..36685.672 rows=3015686 loops=1)
                          Output: public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.usuario_controller, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller, imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei, imeis_isn_tbl.isn, imeis_isn_tbl.imei, imeis_isn_tbl.alias, pos_boyas.id_traza_boya, pos_boyas.num_boya, pos_boyas.latitud_boya, pos_boyas.longitud_boya, pos_boyas.estado_tracking, pos_boyas.estado_flash, pos_boyas.estado_sos, pos_boyas.estado_ack, pos_boyas.estado_gps, pos_boyas.bateria, pos_boyas.fecha_posicion, pos_boyas.velocidad, pos_boyas.rumbo, barcos.id_barco, barcos.nombre_barco
                          Buffers: shared hit=221299 read=2784496 dirtied=5 written=186
                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=308.57..620.66 rows=15 width=87) (actual time=83.267..183.011 rows=1982 loops=1)
                                Output: public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.usuario_controller, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller, usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei, imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei, imeis_isn_tbl.isn, imeis_isn_tbl.imei, imeis_isn_tbl.alias, barcos.id_barco, barcos.nombre_barco
                                Buffers: shared hit=22216 read=1073
                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=308.57..521.23 rows=15 width=76) (actual time=83.237..148.049 rows=1982 loops=1)
                                      Output: public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.usuario_controller, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller, usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei, imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei, imeis_isn_tbl.isn, imeis_isn_tbl.imei, imeis_isn_tbl.alias, comun_imei.id_barco
                                      Buffers: shared hit=17553 read=372
                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=308.57..415.88 rows=15 width=80) (actual time=73.830..120.167 rows=1982 loops=1)
                                            Output: public.usuarios_claves_usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.usuario_controller, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller, usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei, imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei, imeis_isn_tbl.isn, imeis_isn_tbl.imei, imeis_isn_tbl.alias, comun_imei.id_barco
                                            Join Filter: (public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller = public.usuarios_claves_usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=11731 read=247
                                            ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=308.57..318.78 rows=15 width=80) (actual time=73.811..87.641 rows=1982 loops=1)
                                                  Output: public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.usuario_controller, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller, usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl.id_usuario_controller, usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei, imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei, imeis_isn_tbl.isn, imeis_isn_tbl.imei, imeis_isn_tbl.alias, comun_imei.id_barco
                                                  Merge Cond: (imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei = comun_imei.id_isn_imei)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=5911 read=121
                                                  ->  Sort  (cost=157.97..158.01 rows=15 width=76) (actual time=72.856..75.019 rows=1982 loops=1)
                                                        Output: public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.usuario_controller, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller, usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl.id_usuario_controller, usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei, imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei, imeis_isn_tbl.isn, imeis_isn_tbl.imei, imeis_isn_tbl.alias
                                                        Sort Key: usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei
                                                        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 327kB
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=5908 read=104
                                                        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4.37..157.68 rows=15 width=76) (actual time=67.455..72.049 rows=1982 loops=1)
                                                              Output: public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.usuario_controller, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller, usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl.id_usuario_controller, usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei, imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei, imeis_isn_tbl.isn, imeis_isn_tbl.imei, imeis_isn_tbl.alias
                                                              Buffers: shared hit=5908 read=104
                                                              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4.37..52.77 rows=15 width=29) (actual time=67.424..68.430 rows=1982 loops=1)
                                                                    Output: public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.usuario_controller, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller, usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl.id_usuario_controller, usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei
                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=7 read=45
                                                                    ->  Index Scan using usuarios_controllers_tbl_usuario_controller_idx on public.usuarios_controllers_tbl  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=21) (actual time=0.010..0.012 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                                          Output: public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.usuario_controller, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller_zcc, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.cuenta_demo, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.ver_boyas, public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.ver_todos_barcos
                                                                          Index Cond: ((public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.usuario_controller)::text = 'whatever'::text)
                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl  (cost=4.37..44.35 rows=15 width=8) (actual time=67.406..67.944 rows=1982 loops=1)
                                                                          Output: usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl.id_usuario_controller_imei, usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl.id_usuario_controller, usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei
                                                                          Recheck Cond: (usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl.id_usuario_controller = public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller)
                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=4 read=45
                                                                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl_id_usuario_controller_idx  (cost=0.00..4.37 rows=15 width=0) (actual time=67.389..67.389 rows=1982 loops=1)
                                                                                Index Cond: (usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl.id_usuario_controller = public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller)
                                                                                Buffers: shared hit=2 read=7
                                                              ->  Index Scan using imeis_isn_tbl_pkey on public.imeis_isn_tbl  (cost=0.00..6.98 rows=1 width=47) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1982)
                                                                    Output: imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei, imeis_isn_tbl.isn, imeis_isn_tbl.imei, imeis_isn_tbl.tipo_comunicador, imeis_isn_tbl.alias, imeis_isn_tbl.boya_sos, imeis_isn_tbl.gestion_mensajes, imeis_isn_tbl.fecha_ult_modificacion, imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei_tmp, imeis_isn_tbl.bluetooth, imeis_isn_tbl.geofence, imeis_isn_tbl.sonda
                                                                    Index Cond: (imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei = usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei)
                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=5901 read=59
                                                  ->  Sort  (cost=150.59..155.63 rows=2013 width=8) (actual time=0.920..3.696 rows=2007 loops=1)
                                                        Output: comun_imei.id_isn_imei, comun_imei.id_barco
                                                        Sort Key: comun_imei.id_isn_imei
                                                        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 143kB
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=3 read=17
                                                        ->  Seq Scan on public.barcos_imeis_tbl comun_imei  (cost=0.00..40.13 rows=2013 width=8) (actual time=0.011..0.422 rows=2013 loops=1)
                                                              Output: comun_imei.id_isn_imei, comun_imei.id_barco
                                                              Buffers: shared hit=3 read=17
                                            ->  Index Scan using usuarios_claves_usuarios_controllers__id_usuario_controller_idx on public.usuarios_claves_usuarios_controllers_tbl  (cost=0.00..6.46 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.008..0.010 rows=1 loops=1982)
                                                  Output: public.usuarios_claves_usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usu_clave_usu_controller, public.usuarios_claves_usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario, public.usuarios_claves_usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller
                                                  Index Cond: (public.usuarios_claves_usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller = usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl.id_usuario_controller)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=5820 read=126
                                      ->  Index Only Scan using usuarios_claves_tbl_pkey on public.usuarios_claves_tbl  (cost=0.00..7.01 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.010..0.012 rows=1 loops=1982)
                                            Output: public.usuarios_claves_tbl.id_usuario
                                            Index Cond: (public.usuarios_claves_tbl.id_usuario = public.usuarios_claves_usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario)
                                            Heap Fetches: 1982
                                            Buffers: shared hit=5822 read=125
                                ->  Index Scan using barcos_tbl_pkey on public.barcos_tbl barcos  (cost=0.00..6.62 rows=1 width=15) (actual time=0.013..0.015 rows=1 loops=1982)
                                      Output: barcos.id_barco, barcos.nombre_barco
                                      Index Cond: (comun_imei.id_barco = barcos.id_barco)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=4663 read=701
                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.traza_boyas_tbl pos_boyas  (cost=55.85..5047.66 rows=1572 width=87) (actual time=6.041..17.728 rows=1522 loops=1982)
                                Output: pos_boyas.id_traza_boya, pos_boyas.num_boya, pos_boyas.isn, pos_boyas.id_barco, pos_boyas.tipo_boya, pos_boyas.cabecera, pos_boyas.latitud_boya, pos_boyas.longitud_boya, pos_boyas.velocidad, pos_boyas.rumbo, pos_boyas.estado_tracking, pos_boyas.estado_flash, pos_boyas.estado_sos, pos_boyas.estado_ack, pos_boyas.estado_gps, pos_boyas.bateria, pos_boyas.en_agua, pos_boyas.imei, pos_boyas.fecha_posicion, pos_boyas.minutos_ventana_on, pos_boyas.minutos_ventana_off, pos_boyas.alarma_geofence, pos_boyas.estado_geofence, pos_boyas.primer_arranque, pos_boyas.id_isn_imei
                                Recheck Cond: ((pos_boyas.id_isn_imei = usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei) AND (pos_boyas.fecha_posicion >= '20180731140755'::bpchar))
                                Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 535
                                Buffers: shared hit=199083 read=2783423 dirtied=5 written=186
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on traza_boyas_tbl_id_isn_imei_fecha_idx  (cost=0.00..55.45 rows=1572 width=0) (actual time=5.788..5.788 rows=1522 loops=1982)
                                      Index Cond: ((pos_boyas.id_isn_imei = usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei) AND (pos_boyas.fecha_posicion >= '20180731140755'::bpchar))
                                      Buffers: shared hit=5444 read=21095
        ->  Index Scan using estados_notificaciones_imeis_isn_tbl_pkey on public.estados_notificaciones_imeis_isn_tbl estados_notify  (cost=0.00..8.59 rows=1 width=31) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=1 loops=3015686)
              Output: estados_notify.id_isn_imei, estados_notify.fecha_posicion, estados_notify.zona_prohibida, estados_notify.velocidad_lenta, estados_notify.valor_limite_velocidad_lenta, estados_notify.sin_transmision, estados_notify.comprobado, estados_notify.alerta_geofence
              Index Cond: ((imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei = estados_notify.id_isn_imei) AND (pos_boyas.fecha_posicion = estados_notify.fecha_posicion))
              Buffers: shared hit=9572201 read=2409343 dirtied=6 written=797
Total runtime: 215291.446 ms
```

Comment: I hate graphical execution plans (in Postgres just as much as in Oracle or SQL Server). The raw output of `explain (analyze, buffers, format text)` reveals much more details. And in my opinion it's way easier to read.

Comment: Unrelated, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible. And if you have performance problems, then upgrading is a must. Especially Postgres 9.6 and later have implement some substantial performance enhancements

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know that 9.2 is no longer supported but as I stated in my original post, upgrade is not an option by now, and I'm not the one that decides these things. About your first comment, I'll post raw output in a while. I should have done it in advance, sorry.

Comment: Tell those that "decide" on the (non)upgrade that they are risking their business due to the lack of security updates. In some countries and industries it's even illegal to run software that does not receive security patches. [Upgrading from 9.2.24 to 11.5 gives you 2210 security fixes](https://why-upgrade.depesz.com/show?from=9.2.24&to=11.5)  - the (most probably) better performance is then a welcome side effect

Comment: As I've said, I'm aware of the problem with the version. If the only solution is to upgrade PG version, then ok and blame me/us for not upgrading. But I'm sure I can do several things by my own better than upgrade installed sw. So I'd like to ask to leave version problem aside, please, and focus on query performance because that's what I'm asking about. I've edited my original post to include raw explain plan (it's the one loaded in PEV graphic tool).

Comment: It looks like the view includes an `ORDER BY usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl.id_isn_imei` which is a bad idea to begin with (although it only takes 75ms to do that, so it's not the root of the problem). At least one hash join needs to buffer the results on disk. For that increasing `work_mem` could help. And the final `order by` also sorts on disk. So increasing `work_mem` will definitely help here. Start with e.g. `set work_mem='64MB';` depending on your server's memory. Increasing `temp_buffers` should help as well

Comment: The query also seems to contain a lot of self (outer) joins to the same table. Very often this can be done more efficiently but without the full query text (including the underlying view(s) this is impossible to tell). Statistics for `usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl` don't seem to be accurate, but I don't think it makes a big difference

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what you're saying (about outer joins) is that it would be better to rewrite query, am I understanding right? If so, that's one of the things I'm planning to do when team's back. About statistics, I don't know what else can I do as I've run them manually several times in the last week. About changin config params, I'll do it.

Comment: Without seeing the actual query it's impossible to help you with optimizing it. But very often I have seen queries using many self joins that could be optimized by using conditional aggregation instead.

Comment: I am thinking about queries like this one: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/139992

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I don't think I would use that graphical visualizer tool in the first place.  It seems to obfuscate more than it clarifies.

If you trace the "badge" down through the nodes to the bottom-most-one, it seems to correspond to this line from the text entry:

```
->  Bitmap Index Scan on usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl_id_usuario_controller_idx  (cost=0.00..4.37 rows=15 width=0) (actual time=67.389..67.389 rows=1982 loops=1)
 Index Cond: (usuarios_controllers_imeis_isn_tbl.id_usuario_controller = public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller)
```

The index condition here is equating the indexed field, to a field in some other table.  It is using a generic estimate, that a row from the other table has 15 entries in this table.  But the specific row in that other table you actually have found ('whatever') has 1982 rows in this table.  I don't think there is any way to get it to use the specific estimate in this case.  Other than to manually query for `public.usuarios_controllers_tbl.id_usuario_controller` where `usuario_controller = 'whatever'` and then write the value of that into your outer query, which of course is highly undesirable.  You might want to try it and see what would happen, as way of narrowing down the problem.

But, it isn't really clear that a better estimate would lead to a better plan, anyway.  Perhaps it could replace the "Bitmap Heap Scan on `public.traza_boyas_tbl pos_boyas`" with a hash join instead.  But it isn't clear 1) that it would do that and 2) that doing that would actually make things faster.

Comment: Manually query "whatever" and then write the value to the outer query is like rewriting the whole query. So I guess there's nothing to do with the query as is: no indexes nor statistics collection could save the problem.

Comment: You can do the rewrite manually once and see what happens.  If that doesn't make it faster, there is no point in pursuing it further.  If it does make it faster, then you can dig into it more.

Comment: So in the end, the "bad estimate" badge is because at some point in the plan expected rows and retrieved rows doesn't match, and this can be caused by bad statistics or bad execution plan. Am I right?